# Definition of lying above in Neukrich Proposition 9.3

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have a general question about the setup of Proposition 9.3 in Neukirch's algebraic number theory ([http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf))

There, he claims that $\mathfrak{P}_Z = \mathfrak{P} \cap Z_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is the prime ideal of $Z_{\mathfrak{P}}$ below $\mathfrak{P}$. I don't understand this construction: Up to this point, a prime ideal of a field (which $Z_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is) is just a short-hand notation for a prime ideal in the corresponding integral closure. Thus, shouldn't $\mathfrak{P}_Z$ be defined to be the intersection of $\mathfrak{P} \cap \mathcal{O}_{Z_{\mathfrak{P}}}$?

Comment: The elements of $\mathfrak{P}$ are integral so automatically in $\mathcal{O}_{Z_\mathfrak{P}}$

Comment: Oh true: The argument is was missing is that $\mathcal{O}_{L} \cap Z_{\mathfrak{P}} = \mathcal{O}_{Z_\mathfrak{P}}$.